# How to speed up the Haversine formula in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

As a hobby project I started making a website for a company. I am not very advanced in making complicated codes for website but I wanted to give it a try.

I have a zip code database from the Netherlands with over 471000 records in it. I use the haversine formula to look up which postal codes are within the radius of 13 km and then I select every user from the database that has a postalcode in this result. But the formula takes 6 secs to load all the results. How can I speed this process up?

**Code below:**

```
$finder = $mysqli->query("SELECT lat, lng FROM postcodetabel WHERE postcode = '$s' OR plaats = '$s'");
$finder1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($finder);
$latitude = $finder1['lat'];
$longitude = $finder1['lng'];
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT postcode, (
      6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians('$latitude') )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$longitude') )
      + sin ( radians('$latitude') )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM postcodetabel
HAVING distance < 12
ORDER BY distance ASC");

$quertie = $mysqli->query("SELECT bigav, id, naam, email, bedrijfsnaam, telnummer FROM gebruikers WHERE postcode = '$postcode' AND status = 1 AND soort LIKE '%" . $soort . "%'");
while($quertie2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quertie)) { echo '
<div class="kapper">
    <div class="kapperfoto"><img src="/vluggeknipt/ondernemer/pagina/uploads/'.$quertie2['bigav'].'" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="boektekst">
        <font class="headingkap"><strong><a href="?page=profiel&id='.$quertie2['id'].'">Naar profiel &raquo;</a></strong></font><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="kappertext">
        <font class="headingkap"><a href="?page=profiel&id='.$quertie2['id'].'"><strong>'.$quertie2['naam'].'</strong></a></font><br/>
        <i class="mobhide">'.$quertie2['email'].' - '.$quertie2['telnummer'].'</i><br/>
        <i class="mobhide">'.$quertie2['bedrijfsnaam'].'</i>
    </div></div><br/>

    '; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This query will never be especially fast. However, there are some ways it can be improved.

**First:** The Haversine formula is not necessary here. The corrections which it applies are only necessary when the curvature of the earth is a significant factor, or very near the poles. Neither of these are the case here -- the largest distance which needs to be calculated accurately is 12 miles, which is barely even over the horizon. On this scale, the earth is effectively flat, so the Pythagorean Theorem is good enough for calculating distances.

One degree of latitude is about 69 miles, and at 52°N (around where the Netherlands are), a degree of longitude is `cos(52°) x 69 = 42.5` miles, so the formula becomes:

```
sqrt(pow(69*(lat - $latitude), 2) + pow(42.5*(lng - $longitude), 2))
```

**Second:** we can use a "scissor test" for latitude and longitudes. If a point is more than 12 miles in any cardinal direction from your target point, it certainly cannot be within a 12-mile circle of that point. We can use this fact to perform a fast comparison on the latitude and longitude, skipping the distance calculation entirely. Using the figures for one degree of latitude/longitude we derived above, we have:

```
WHERE (lat BETWEEN ($latitude  - 12/69.0) AND ($latitude  + 12/69.0))
  AND (lng BETWEEN ($longitude - 12/42.5) AND ($longitude + 12/42.5))
```

Note that this doesn't replace the full distance check! It's simply a first step to quickly throw out points that can't possibly be within the right radius. With an index in place on `lat` or `lng`, this will allow the database server to avoid examining many of the rows in the database.

Comment: Great answer! Can you (/ anyone) give an indication of the upper limit on distances for which this method is reasonably accurate? Say, within 5% of the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

why yoy are uing HAVING  ...due the fact that your query don'use aggregated  function so you can filter uing where  (but where don't use you must repate  the code ) and for performance using where avoid a full scan for reaise the result  for having  evaluation

```
  $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT postcode, (
        6371 * acos (
        cos ( radians('$latitude') )
        * cos( radians( lat ) )
        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$longitude') )
        + sin ( radians('$latitude') )
        * sin( radians( lat ) )
      )
  ) AS distance
  FROM postcodetabel
  WHERE    6371 * acos (
        cos ( radians('$latitude') )
        * cos( radians( lat ) )
        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$longitude') )
        + sin ( radians('$latitude') )
        * sin( radians( lat ) ) )< 12
  ORDER BY distance ASC");
```